# Perform action on all enum values not passed to method

Tags: c#, enums, compare, coded-ui-tests

I have 5 checkboxes labeled `A`,`B`,`C`,`D` and `E` which I've created an `enum` for.  They are checked by default.  I'd like to pass a method the enum which I would like to leave checked and uncheck all the rest.  How would you go about doing this the most efficiently, this is what I've got, any thoughts?

So in example below if I passed `Type.A` to `CheckType` I would expect only `CheckboxA` to still be checked at the end.

```
public enum Type
{
    A,
    B,        
    C,
    D,
    E
}

public class SelectorPage
{
    public void CheckType(Type type)
    {
        if (type != Type.A)
        {
            if (ACheckBox.Exists)
            {
                CheckA(false);
            }
        }

        if (type != Type.B)
        {
            if (BCheckBox.Exists)
            {
                CheckB(false);
            }
        }

        if (type != Type.C)
        {
            if (CCheckBox.Exists)
            {
                CheckC(false);
            }
        }

        if (type != Type.D)
        {
            if (DCheckBox.Exists)
            {
                CheckD(false);
            }
        }

        if (type != Type.E)
        {
            if (ECheckBox.Exists)
            {
                CheckE(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @GrantWinney The only context given about the environment is `coded-ui-tests`, there's no guarantee that a `RadioButton` exists or is available. However, that would be a valid approach if it was `WinForms` etc...

Comment: Yeah it's a codedui test, I don't have control over the ui I'm testing. Thanks for the help, want to make sure I do everything as efficiently as possible while learning c#.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following is pretty self explanatory :)

```
public class SelectorPage
{
    public void CheckType(Type type)
    {
        if (ACheckBox.Exists)
            CheckA(type == Type.A);

        if (BCheckBox.Exists)
            CheckB(type == Type.B);

        if (CCheckBox.Exists)
            CheckC(type == Type.C);

        if (DCheckBox.Exists)
            CheckD(type == Type.D);

        if (ECheckBox.Exists)
            CheckE(type == Type.E);
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this big improvement over mine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void CheckType(Type type)
{
    Dictionary<Type, CheckBox> map = new Dictionary<Type, CheckBox>
    {
        { ACheckBox, Type.A }, 
        { BCheckBox, Type.B },
        { CCheckBox, Type.C },
        { DCheckBox, Type.D },
        { ECheckBox, Type.E },
    }

    foreach(var pair in map)
    {
        CheckBox checkBox = pair.Key;
        Type checkBoxType = pair.Value;
        if(checkBox.Exists)
        {
            bool shouldBeChecked = checkBoxType == type;
            checkBox.Check(shouldBeChecked);
        }   
    }
}
```